# Is it possible to set up a tezos node to watch a smart contract?

Tags: node, tezos-client

When running a Tezos node, is it possible to set up a subscription service so that you can be notified of transactions spending from, or interacting with a smart contract?

For example, if you want your node to notify you every time there's a transfer to or from contract KT1SC7...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something you could use, https://github.com/ecadlabs/tezos-streamer

Try using google next time. I simply searched "tezos streaming" and found this result on page 1.